# Replacement for DropShadowBitmapEffect in WPF4

Tags: wpf, wpf-4.0

I cannot find a canonical answer for this. I have many effects such as

```
<Label Content="SomeLabel">
  <Label.BitmapEffect>
    <DropShadowBitmapEffect/>
  </Label.BitmapEffect>
</Label>
```

`BitMapEffect` is deprecated in WPF4 and simply stopped working. What is the easiest migration path for a simple drop shadow on a label?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its just `Effect` now

```
<Label Content="StackOverflow" >
    <Label.Effect>
        <DropShadowEffect />
    </Label.Effect>
</Label>
```